# How to add lead attributes in a chained-attribute expression?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

In Progress 4GL I need to export some data as XML to the client. But for some case I need to add lead attributes in a chained-attribute. Can you help this case? You can see my code down.

```
  hOutSAXDocument:START-DOCUMENT(). 
  hOutSAXDocument:START-ELEMENT("DataItems").
  hOutSAXDocument:START-ELEMENT("DataItem").
  hOutSAXDocument:INSERT-ATTRIBUTE("Name","Date"):INSERT-ATTRIBUTE("Type","String").
```

You can see the fourth line I have added lead attributes in a chined attribute but syntex is not correct. I dont know how to solve this issue but generating XML will be like this

```
<DataItem Name="Date" Type="String" Class="col-md-6 rowheader">
```

Comment: I've retyped the text from the XML screenshot. Please do not post text as images.

Answer (score 0):

```
hOutSAXDocument:START-DOCUMENT(). 
hOutSAXDocument:START-ELEMENT("DataItems").
  hOutSAXDocument:START-ELEMENT("DataItem").
  hOutSAXDocument:INSERT-ATTRIBUTE("Name","Date").
hOutSAXDocument:INSERT-ATTRIBUTE("Type","String").
```

Comment: Actually the code you have written will not give all attributes in a single row.it will give each and every attributes one by one.As you know my concern is need to produce an XML with two attributes in one element in one row. Can you please help this case?